# Cognito multi-tenant user pools

Tags: amazon-cognito, multi-tenant, aws-amplify

My Angular application needs to support multiple tenants as well as social logins like Facebook and Google.  We are using AWS Cognito with Amplify.  When setting up Cognito's app client, we can enter multiple sign-in and sign-out URLs used in the authentication flow between my app and federated providers like Facebook and Google.

I'm anticipating each tenant will have a unique URL - something like `https://tenantA.my-app.com` and `https://tenantB.my-app.com`.

**How do you configure Cognito's sign-in and sign-out URLs to support multi-tenants, each with a different URL?**  Surely there's a better way then to keep sign-in and sign-out URLs configuration up-to-date with all valid tenant URLs?

With Angular, I can configure amplify with dynamic values for oauth.redirectSignIn and oauth.redirectSignOut.   I'm unsure how to make Cognito's user pool reflect dynamic URLs representing each tenant.

Is it possible to have a 'clearing-house' url which Facebook and Google return to after authentication then this 'clearing-house' destination would redirect authenticated user to the correct tenant?  I'm grasping at straws.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: we did a similar app (but React), after some discussions, we ended up using a Cognito User Pool per tenant. That also would separate tenants users and allows more flexibility. Tenants' Cognito config was dynamically generated by a lambda and stored in the tenant's folder (website). So, the app can easily link Amplify to the appropriate Cognito Pool.

Comment: I am also working on a Multi-Tenant application as well using AWS Amplify and AWS Cognito, [SaaS on AWS Bootcamp](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-saas-factory-bootcamp) has everything that you need and the examples they use are done in Angular as well.

Comment: I gave up on AWS Cognito for multi-tenancy and went with Auth0